# How to access efi boot partition as read-write?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, uefi, bootloader, read-only

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows 8 (efi mode) and now I want to go to a **read-write** access of the **efi boot partition**.

For secure boot to work, I installed the Linux Foundation's PreLoader. Then I enabled root account login to access the efi boot partition. I have copied the boot loader, but now the efi boot partition mounts as read-only.

When I try to change the folder permissions, it says:

```
Error setting permissions:Read-only filesystem
```

I have already tried the following command in root:

```
mount -o remount,rw /folder1/folder2/targetFolder
```

It is still read-only.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out my self ...
i **used chkdsk command in windows 8 and it repaired the partition.**

thanks if anybody took pain to solve this ..
i would have deleted this question the same day i posted it here but i don't know how to.
sorry

Comment: Mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was most likely caused by a new Windows 8 feature called "fast startup." This feature turns a Windows shutdown operation into a suspend-to-disk function, which in turn means that the filesystems are not properly unmounted, which means that they cannot be safely mounted in any other OS. Thus, on systems that dual-boot with Windows 8, it's ***IMPERATIVE*** that fast startup be disabled, as described here:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

Comment: i knew about the windows fast boot issue with linux and already figured the way around(created a shortcut to command line shutdown that shutdows the windows in old way) and can **ACCESS THE DRIVES in UBUNTU..** but i ran fsck in ubuntu and there was some **cluster mismatch issue** and another error found during  **ubuntu recovery mode** a **superblock could not be read**.

Comment: and i used the chkdsk in cmd prompt that **repaired the efi boot partiion**

Answer (score 0):

first mount device

```
sudo mount -o rw /dev/nvme /media/user/target
```

check mount location then use sudo user for any command

```
sudo cp /home/user/file.conf /media/user/target/
```